# App Engine copy datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

I am now on python 2.7 and have datastore admin working I want to copy the datastore from one app to another. All the documentation I find refers to Python 2.5 where is the how to do this for Python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datastore Admin is independent of the version you're using, so you don't have to worry about it. Please just enable Datastore Admin via the Admin Console.

Comment: Yes but you have to add something for copying the data

Comment: Now Python2.7 runtime allows remote_api builtin, so it'll just work if you follow the procedure described in our [doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#A_Note_for_Java_Developers).